# Custom analyzer elasticsearch soundex plus snowball

Tags: search, elasticsearch, soundex, snowball

The following works for me (searching for 'testing' also returns fields with 'test'):

`index :
  analysis :
    analyzer :
      default :
        type : snowball
        language : english`

when set up in my elasticsearch.yml file .

I want to combine this with the soundex I have installed so I have tried this :

`index :
  analysis :
    analyzer :
      default :
        type : custom
        tokenizer : standard
        filter : [standard, lowercase, soundex_filter, stemming]
    filter :
      soundex_filter :
        type : phonetic
        encoder : soundex
        replace : true
      stemming :
        type : snowball
        language : english`

but no success, none of them seems to work (no stemming or soundex)

Anybody had any success at combining filters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those interested, here is the right syntax

`index :
  analysis :
    analyzer :
      default :
        type : custom
        tokenizer : standard
        filter : [standard, lowercase, stemming_filter, soundex_filter]
    filter :
      soundex_filter :
        type : phonetic
        encoder : soundex
        replace : false
      stemming_filter :
        type : snowball
        language : English`

replace true was somehow overriding the stemming...